# How to send contents of a variable from Javascript to HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I would like to fill the text value with a Javascript variable:

```
<input type="text" name="abc" "  id="abc" value=""/>
```

Just as is done in PHP.

```
<input type="text" name="abc"  id="abc" value="<?php echo "$str[5]";?>"/>
```

But if I use Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('abc').value = str[5];
```

or jQuery:

```
$("#abc").data(str[3], $("#abc").val(str[5]));
```

I get to fill the text area correctly, but it is not the same thing as with the PHP example. How to send the contents of a variable from Javascript to HTML?

pardon I try to explain better I would like to change the value in quotation marks

```
value=""
```

but through javascript 
as easily as you get from php

thank you very much

Luca

Comment: you can not access php variables from javascript directly, you should use the tags <? as HTML

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP where you are creating the HTML, have PHP print out the variable like so..

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('abc').value = <?php echo "$str[5]";?>;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#abc").data(str[3], $("#abc").val(<?php echo "$str[5]";?>));
```